# Are Doflamingo's Fakes waterproof?

Tags: one-piece

What would happen if Doflamingo's Fakes touches water? Are they proofed against water?

In the Chapter 752, Doflamingo appears as a "Fake" Doflamingo

> [image]
>  [image]

- **Would Doflamingo lose his power?**
- **Would the fake Doflamingo lose his power or is he immune against water?**

Comment: I think he would lose power since the strings are still part of his body being a stringman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for Paramacia the sea only affects the user and not the effects of the fruit.  Example: Luffy's neck was still stretchable after being submerged in water during the Arlong Arc, while Luffy himself was not able to move. Vander Decken IX's tracking ability worked even while it went underwater, as well as Whitebeard's earthquake fruit got transmuted through the sea to the ocean floor.

So as long as Doflamingo's not in the water himself his powers or extension thereof shouldnt be affected.

@Rajven What is the basis for this? His clone could have ended due to the attack it sustained from the other revolters.

Comment: to support your answer there another case where **Aokiji** use ice age to freeze sea water while fighting with **White Beard** and when **Luffy** meets him for the first time.

Comment: But isn't the string part of his body? Isn't his body made of strings? Or is that only the clone's?

Comment: @Peter Raeves so far only the clones have been shown to be all string.  Even when the head was cut it was a clone. They have yet to reveal if he is made of string or can generate/control things with string.

Comment: @Quikstryke I hope he is entirely out of strings, the same way Luffy is entirely out of rubber. That would make him even more badass then he already is.

Comment: I just went through some of the wikis. Seems he is paramecia and can generate and control strings.

Answer (score 1):

We see in the manga Devil's Fruit powers emanations that falls in the see, have effect and then disappear much or less slowly.
The string clone'd encounter the same end in the water.

Answer (score 1):

**They are waterproof.**

> Paramecia is one of the three Devil Fruit types. These fruits give the users a power that can affect their body, manipulate the environment, or produce substances.

There are three different types of [Paramecia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Paramecia), and Doflamingo seems to be the third type. He can produce strings, rather than his body being made of strings. We have clearly see him get hurt and bleed and additionally have we seen strings separated from his body, still being intact (eg: birdcage). The strings that he produces come out of his body and are thus not part of it any more. He can manipulate their shape and structure, and he can use his parasite technique to make them move, but they are just strings and nothing more.

Proof that they are indeed separate and do not affect him, has been given in chapter 787.

> When Franky and the Tontatta try to push back the birdcage with the seastone factory, the strings are basically touching seastone, yet we don't see them nor Doflamingo get any weaker. So whether it be the birdcage or the string clones he makes, regardless of them being touched by water or seastone, they will not lose their power.
>
>  [image]

---

On a sidenote, it seems that this effect happens with every paramecia that produces things, except for Robin. I think, Robin **would** be affected if her hands touch the sea(stone). I'm basing this on the fact that she could be turned into a doll, by touching one of her *limbs*, while similarly it does not seem like Doflamgino would be turned into a doll if his cage or clone was touched.